# Jupyter Notebook print env yml as cell output without saving to file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, yaml

How can I print my environment yaml to an output cell in a Jupyter notebook without creating the actual file?

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: As I see the answer wasn't what you were looking for I'll respond here. I believe the answer is you can't. The yaml file is just there for creating the environment itself, it doesn't get saved into the environment inherently. You could generate a requirements.txt using `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt` to get the current environment as it is.
I see Sparrow0hawk has a suggestion, I would try that - if it results in the yaml file then I stand corrected.

Comment: @JosephBradshaw the answer from Sparrow0hawk indeed worked and was what I was looking for, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have an environment file you can call the conda command in the jupyter notebook and run it using the shell with:

```
! conda env export --from-history
```

The `--from-history` option will ensure your output is [just the packages you've installed via conda](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#exporting-an-environment-file-across-platforms). The full specification can be retrieved with:

```
! conda env export
```

Comment: Nice, these work exactly as you described, thanks!!